# Page covering div not showing on mobile hybrid app

Tags: html, css, meta, pinchzoom, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a div that is centered, fixed, and covering the entire page on a mobile hybrid app. For some reason this div will flash for a second when the page is loading, but it never shows as it is suppose to show.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach for setting an absolute/fixed div that covers an entire page will often include css that is similar to this.

- Centering a fixed div

  ```
  left:0;right:0;;top:0;bottom:0; margin:auto;
  ```
- Setting up the covering image

  ```
  background-image: url('http://cdn.idstatic.com/cms/live/190/Untitled-1.gif?1401950829'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50%; background-color: #fff;left:0;
  ```

Presto! You now have a center and fixed div, but it doesn't work on your mobile hybrid pages! It only works on your desktop devices.

Sometimes you may find that you have a meta tag that is used to disable pinch zoom on mobile devices. Removing this will allow you to have a fixed centered div on your responsive mobile hybrid page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```